# Ag grid Check if last row is new

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a `grid` that can create a new `row` via `updateRowData()`.  Now what I want to do is add a link to the new row via `cellrenderer`.
**My question now is, is there a way to check if the last row created is a new row?**  I have looked into the params and can't seem to find anything that says if the row is just created.

Below is the code I'm working on at the moment.  I am calling this through the cellRenderer variable in the column definitions.  Kindly look into the iCreate element of my code regarding my question.

```
`customCellRendererFunc(params: any): any{
    const _this = this;
    const mainDiv = document.createElement('div');

    if(
      Object.entries(params.node.childrenMapped).length === 0 &&
      params.node['field'] !== undefined
    ){ 
      const iEdit = document.createElement('i');
      const iCreate = document.createElement('i');
      const originalLength = params.node.allLeafChildren.length;
      const data = params.node.allLeafChildren[0].data;
      const billingruleID = data.billingruleID;

      iEdit.className = 'fa';
      iEdit.classList.add('fa-edit');
      iEdit.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
      iEdit.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer; margin-left:10px;');
      iEdit.addEventListener('click', function() { 

      });

      iCreate.className = 'fa';
      iCreate.classList.add('fa-plus-circle');
      iCreate.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
      iCreate.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer; margin-left:10px;');
      iCreate.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const length = params.node.allLeafChildren.length;

        if(length <= originalLength) {
          const index = length - 1;
          const node = params.node.allLeafChildren[index];
          const newNode = _this.createNewRow(node.data);

          _this.gridApi.updateRowData({ add: [newNode] });
        } else {
          _this.displayDialog("Notice", "Kindly save previous record first 
before creating new one.");
          return false;
        }
      });

      mainDiv.appendChild(iCreate);
      mainDiv.appendChild(iEdit);
    } else if(!params.node.group && params.node.lastChild) {
      const iRemove = document.createElement('i');

      iRemove.className = 'fa';
      iRemove.classList.add('fa-trash');
      iRemove.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
      iRemove.setAttribute('style', 'cursor: pointer; margin-left:10px;');

      mainDiv.appendChild(iRemove);
    }

    return mainDiv;
  }`
```

Comment: please share your implementation of ag grid.

Comment: You are not passing 'addIndex' field to 'updateRowData' function, so it will always append data to end of your list. It means last row will be the new one. Inside cellrenderer you can compare length of your data with 'rowIndex' field of params.

Comment: Hi, will try to compare the length to rowIndex.  I have been looking into the addIndex but i believe it is no longer being used by ag-grid as it is stated in their site that:

"The index to add is put in for historical purposes and should not be used. If you want the grid to display in a certain order, you should set deltaRowDataMode=true and then set row data, which will maintain the row order while also working out the update, deletes and adds for you."

Comment: Where did you saw that, I am still able to use addIndex, with ag-grid 22.1.0 and angular 7

Comment: Here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#adding-rows

Comment: Also here are my versions: "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.2",

Comment: ok, let me know, if rowIndex works for you..